# Как соединить(замкнуть) ломаную? Без добавления первой точки в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

````
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

platforms = [
    [(500, 420), (170, 300), (420, 140), (300, 390)],
    [(460, 230), (250, 310), (100, 520)],
    [(300, 500), (470, 390), (270, 200)]
]
...
...
        def draw_platform(platform):
            x, y = map_point(platform[0][0], platform[0][1])
            # print("platform_move_x:", x, "platform_move_y:", y)
            path.moveTo(x, y)
            for x, y in platform[1:]:
                x, y = map_point(x, y)
                # print("platform_line_x:", x, "platform_line_y:", y)
                path.lineTo(x, y)

        for platform in platforms:
            draw_platform(platform)
        qp.drawPath(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

platforms = [
    [(500, 420), (170, 300), (420, 140), (300, 390)],
    [(460, 230), (250, 310), (100, 520)],
    [(300, 500), (470, 390), (270, 200)]
]
...
...
        def draw_platform(platform):
            x, y = map_point(platform[0][0], platform[0][1])
            path.moveTo(x, y)
            for x, y in platform[1:]:
                x, y = map_point(x, y)
                path.lineTo(x, y)

            # Просто добавьте ещё одну линию от конца к началу:
            x, y = map_point(platform[0][0], platform[0][1])
            path.lineTo(x, y)

        for platform in platforms:
            draw_platform(platform)
        qp.drawPath(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```